# Why I obtain this HibernateException (Errors in named queries) related to my JPQL query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpql

I am absolutly new in Hibernate and I have the following problem defining a JPQL query into an application.

So I have the following situation:

1) I have this model **KMCountryArea** class that is annoted to map it to a DB table and a query is definied

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmCountryListByName", query = "SELECT country FROM KMCountryArea country WHERE country.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by country.idCountry")
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "KM_COUNTRY_AREA")
public class KMCountryArea implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idCountryArea;

    @Column(name = "nomeFolder")
    private String nomeFolder;

    //@Column(name = "country")
    //@OneToOne(mappedBy = "country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToOne
    private KMCountry country;

    public Long getIdCountryArea() {
        return idCountryArea;
    }

    public void setIdCountryArea(Long idCountryArea) {
        this.idCountryArea = idCountryArea;
    }

    public String getNomeFolder() {
        return nomeFolder;
    }

    public void setNomeFolder(String nomeFolder) {
        this.nomeFolder = nomeFolder;
    }

    public KMCountry getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(KMCountry country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the previous code snippet I defined a **JPQL query** named **kmCountryListByName**, this one:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmCountryListByName", query = "SELECT country FROM KMCountryArea country WHERE country.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by country.idCountry")
})
```

2) Then I have a **DAO** defining an interface named **KMCountryAreaService**, this one:

```
public interface KMCountryAreaService {

    @Transactional
    public List<KMCountry> getCountryListByName(Long idCountry);

}
```

that is implemented by the **KMCountryAreaServiceImpl** concrete class:

```
@Repository("kmCountryAreaService")
public class KMCountryAreaServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements KMCountryAreaService {

    public List<KMCountry> getCountryListByName(Long idCountry){
        List<KMCountry> list = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("kmCountryListByName");
        return list;
    }

}
```

So, as you can see, the **getCountryListByName()** method obtain the **kmCountryListByName** that I defined into the model class (**KMCountryArea**).

The problem is that when I try to startup my application (it is a LifeRay portal but I think that it is not important) I obtain the following error message in the stacktrace:

```
 <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: :org.hibernate.HibernateException:Errors in named queries: kmCountryListByName
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

It seems that I have some error on my JPQL query (the one named **kmCountryListByName** defined into the model class) or maybe into the **KMCountryAreaServiceImpl** service implementation.

Why? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You have `order by country.idCountry`, but the field is actually named `idCountryArea`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "kmCountryListByName", query = "SELECT c FROM KMCountryArea c WHERE c.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by c.idCountryArea")
```

})

You have a country property, at the same time you are trying to make alias with the country name.
Or are you trying to join them?

If you try to join them and order by a specific property in the Country object you can try something like this

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "kmCountryListByName", query = "SELECT c FROM KMCountryArea c JOIN c.country cc WHERE c.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by cc.idCountry")
```

In the example above you can see the join between the two objects and order by clause based on the Country object property

Comment: It seems work. The application start now and I have not the exception